# Android react-native deep linking and application embedded browser

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I have a react-native application which use deep linking for Android.

Basically I have a working setup, which means that when im testing on a real device if I go to my website page displaying a link mapped by the `AndroidManifest.xml`, my app is correctly opening when clicking on the link. Same thing when I'm clicking the mapped link directly from Gmail app or Slack, everything works correctly.

However, when I'm going to my website page (which is displaying the mapped link) from the "embedded" Gmail or Slack browser and clicking on the link, the deep link doesn't work and it redirects on the web directly without asking to open the app first.

It seems a strange behaviour for me and after some research I wasn't able to find an explanation or a solution, so anyone have an idea on how to handle this ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you talking about applink or basic deeplink?

Comment: Regular deeplink, formated like `https://example.com/bar`